# Why do I need to use function as an argument and can't just use the value it returns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm looking through a tutorial that covers DOM changing.

Here's an example from that tutorial.

HTML part:

```
<h1>My Awesome Post</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
```

Script

```
(function() {
  $('p').eq(0).after(function() {
    return $(this).prev();
  });
})();
```

I don't get why do I need to use the function here if all it does is returning a value? Why the following statement doesn't work?

```
$('p').eq(0).after( $(this).prev());
```

Comment: Related: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: please post full jquery block, as "this" will represent that selector or object to which you are attaching function

Comment: because $(this) isn't what you think it is when you write it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about scope, and the value of `this`

In the first example the function creates a new scope, as all functions do, where `this` is the currently iterated element, as jQuery iterates over the collection of elements internally and sets the value of `this` accordingly

```
$('p').eq(0).after(function() { // new scope, where "this" is the element
    return $(this).prev();
});
```

In the second code, there is no special scope set, so the scope is whatever scope the code is within, most likely the window scope, or if it's in a `$(document).ready` scope, `this` would be the document

```
$('p').eq(0).after( $(this).prev()); // there is no scope here
```

You can read more about [functions and function scope on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
function() {
    return $(this).prev();
```

The "this" refers to the element that it finds, where in your attempt it does not.

If you want to shorten it you can try

```
$('p').eq(0).after($(this).prev());
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` in the second version likely returns the Window object. Experiment with `console.log(this)` at various points to understand how it's meaning changes. Something like this would also produce the result you're expecting:

```
var b = $('p').eq(0).prev();
$('p').eq(0).after(b);
```